# In sklearn Pipeline, why are all parameters fit_transform(), but the last one can be just fit()?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I am reading through *Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn & TensorFlow*. We are going over scikit-learn Transformation Pipelines for preparing data for the machine learning algorithms.

Here is the code (`housing_num` is a dataframe of the numerical attributes of the main dataframe housing):

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', Imputer(strategy='median')),
    ('attribs_adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())
])

housing_num_tr = num_pipeline.fit_transform(housing_num)
```

The text explains:

> The Pipeline constructor takes a list of name/estimator pairs defining
> a sequence of steps. All but the last estimator must be transformers
> (i.e., they must have a `fit_transform()` method).

1. Why do we `fit_transform()` some, but only `fit()` without transforming others? I am guessing this has to do with the difference between estimators and transformers, which I am confused on in this context.
2. So when using `Pipeline`, you can only include one estimator that won't be transformed, and it has to be the last input? ("all but the last estimator must be transformers")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [center the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) (make it have zero mean and unit standard error), you subtract the mean and then divide the result by the standard deviation.

$$z' = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$

or

$$z = ln(x)$$

You do that on the training set of data. But then you have to apply the same transformation to your testing set (e.g. in cross-validation), or to newly obtained examples before forecast. But you have to use the same two parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (values) that you used for centering the training set.

Hence, every sklearn's transform's `fit()` just calculates the parameters (e.g. $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in case of [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)) and saves them as an internal objects state. Afterwards, you can call its `transform()` method to apply the transformation to a particular set of examples.

`fit_transform()` joins these two steps and is used for the initial fitting of parameters on the training set $x$, but it also returns a transformed $x'$. Internally, it just calls first `fit()` and then `transform()` on the same data.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot more sense. Thank you! But I'm still confused on one statement made in the book about Pipeline: "All but the last estimator must be transformers (i.e., they must have a fit_transform() method)." Is there some rule when using sklearn Pipeline that all but the last estimator must be transformers? If so, why? Thanks.

Comment: In the pipeline, each intermediate step is data preparation; if running the pipeline only ran their `fit` methods, they wouldn't actually _do_ anything.  But the last step is often fitting a model, where transforming doesn't make any sense.